# Why do some people in The Sarah Jane Adventures not know about aliens?

Tags: doctor-who, the-sarah-jane-adventures

Of course in the Doctor Who Universe the people of the world became aware of the existence of aliens due to the repeated failed invasions.

But I noticed while watching The Sarah Jane Adventures was that every new character they introduce in the series is very surprised to hear about aliens existing, like they have never heard anything about any previous invasions (except the invasions that occurred in this spin-off series).

How do they not remember these past invasions?

Comment: Torchwood is very *VERY* good at covering these things up. =P

Comment: Because there's a whole world of dumb people

Comment: @Valorum  -  because they're *schmucks*?

Answer (score 4):

I can provide 1 explanation which relates to the Slithereen, having just rewatched the episode. 
At the end, Rose's friend shows the  Doctor a newspaper headline reading "Alien Hoax".  People are much happier NOT having their horizons expanded.

Answer (score -1):

They are so self-involved as to not notice the aliens. Head down on their phones, gabbing with their friends, etc etc. This was the explanation given for Donna's obliviousness.

Comment: This only explained Donna's obliviousness. She kept missing them (which is the joke) but even she had seen the aliens on TV.